# What is a good library for displaying thousands of thumbnails in my application?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm interested in creating a desktop application to help organize large image collections.

Are there any libraries out there that aid in the creation of huge thumbnail galleries, with the ability to "group" and display these thumbnails at arbitrary positions?  Also the ability to scale them would be nice as well.

Is this something I'm going to have to make on my own or does anything like this exist?

Comment: You'll need to explain why Graphics.DrawImage() isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a huge gallery you might want to consider Deep Zoom in a Silverlight desktop app.